# Building VoIP Lan to Apartment Lan

Tags: router, lan, voip, sip

I am quite new on network engineering (coming from programming background). Got stuck at this problem.

**Example 1**

[image]

I have an ASUS RT-AX86U AX5700 router and the building has a 2N Helios IP Verso intercom system.

We have VoIP system (gates, doors and etc.) whenever people call you receive call to your tablet (communication goes through SIP if that matters). There are many tablets in the building all of them have static IP which decides to whom you call. (e.g. if person calls 235 call goes to `192.168.100.235`, if person calls `105` call goes to `192.168.100.105` and so on...). All of the tables can be connected through cloud thus they have connection to internet. (although its limited for specific domains and I don't use it).

The tablet is quite bad, so I decided to remove it.

This is what I am trying to achieve.

**Example 2**

[image]

Connect buildings router/switch to my router/switch and pass SIP calls to one of my computer (raspberry pi in this case), as well this computer should see devices not only in it's own LAN, but in building LAN (for gate/door opening).

#### I have no control of buildings router/switch.

So far what I understand what I have to do is:

- Put static route on my router so all request for `192.168.100.x` would go through connected building lan cable.
- Set my router IP to `192.168.100.235` so buildings router/switch can recognize me.

Problem is if I change my router IP `192.168.100.235` all of my personal LAN devices IP would change and DHCP range would be on `192.168.100.x` which will interfere with building devices.

Is there a way to deal with this?

Comment: How many devices are we talking about. If you assign one router a static IP address of the other, then create another subnet, both subnet’s should be able to communicate with one another. However, without the ability to configure all devices on the network, there isn’t a solution you can implement

Comment: The building infrastructure is always expanding as new buildings around being built and being connected all together (more gates/tablets). Are you suggesting assigning 192.168.100.235 to router and making subnet mask 255.255.255.235? There is still devices in range 192.168.100.236 and higher. My subnet would interfere, unless... I make subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 and DHCP IP pool would start from completely different range (e.g. 192.168.254.x). Am I going towards correct answer?